# Check if component is active to hide it

Tags: vue.js

I created a array of objects and I render them based on a click event. Is there any way using Vue that If I click for example the 'survival' button, if it's already set as the activeCategory, it hides itself? Like an accordion behavior.

```
    .store__categories
    StoreCategoryButton(
     icon='/images/ui/alarm.svg',
     title='survival',
     @click.native='SetActiveCategory("survival")'
    )
  .category__items(v-if='activeCategory === "survival"')
    StoreCategoryItems(v-for='(item, index) in SurvivalItems',
    :title='item.title',
    :icon='item.icon',
    :price='item.price')
    
  .store__categories
    StoreCategoryButton(
     icon='/images/ui/checkbox-active.svg',
     title='War Mode',
     @click.native='SetActiveCategory("war")'
    )
  .category__items(v-if='activeCategory === "war"')
    StoreCategoryItems(v-for='(item, index) in warItems',
    :title='item.title',
    :icon='item.icon',
    :price='item.price',
    :quantity='item.quantity')
```

Data:

```
activeCategory: '',
```

Methods:

```
methods: {
    SetActiveCategory(category) {
      this.activeCategory = category
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, in your method you can check if the `activeCategory` is already the same `category` and in that case set it back to the default of `''`:

```js
methods: {
    SetActiveCategory(category) {
        if (this.activeCategory !== category) {
          this.activeCategory = category
        } else {
          this.activeCategory = ''
        }
    }
}
```